# crash when implementing gestures in xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios

Whenever i try to implement any gesture in xcode 4.2 my app crashes.  I get the following error:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I have added pinch in storyboard, added the code and connected gesture to view controller

```
.h file
- (IBAction) pinch: (UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) pinch;

.m
 - (IBAction) pinch: (UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) pinch{
    pinch.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinch.view.transform, pinch.scale,pinch.scale); 
    pinch.scale =1;
 }
```

I'm new at this so please bear with me if I've done something really silly

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace of the crash?

Comment: I would do but dont know what that is, also ive deleted the project now as i couldn't get it to work... Thank you anyway

Comment: If you have deleted the project what help are you hoping for as you can't provide us with information or agree that the answer worked

Comment: This has happened before when using gestures so i thought it may be a common problem i was doing rather than a specific coding issue, i didn't realise what information I needed to provided.

Answer (score 0):

Storyboards and adding gesture from nibs are only for iOS 5.x

It will always crash on 4.x .